# How do I add words to the OS X user dictionary?

Tags: macos, dictionary

If someone has a word that they commonly use, but OS X Lion keeps "correcting" to something in it's dictionary, how does the user add the word to Lion's dictionary?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Right click on the word and choose Spelling and Grammar from the list. Then select Show Spelling and Grammar.

You'll see the option to "learn" the word (see picture).

[image]

The learned words are stored in `~/Library/Spelling/`. `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary` applies to all languages and for example `~/Library/Spelling/en` only applies to U.S. English. When you press the learn button, the word is added to `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary` if the spelling language is set to automatic or to `~/Library/Spelling/en` if the spelling language is set to U.S. English.

If you edit the files in `~/Library/Spelling/` directly, you can apply the changes by terminating the `AppleSpell` process. Just quitting and reopening applications does not apply the changes.

Comment: Is this data kept in a file somewhere that I could sync between machines?  Where is that file?

Comment: @BillNace I have modified my answer to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

It works not only for words but for sentences too; in my case the long fixed-form greetings used at the start and finish of messages in Japanese which are PITA to type on an iphone. :-)

Comment: Should this be a comment to an answer or the question?